# gRPC RpcException when connecting to server

Tags: c#, rpc, grpc

I have a gRPC Server and Client (in C#). The Server is up and running (tested with grpcc from https://github.com/njpatel/grpcc). But whenever I try to connect with my client. I get following error.

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Cancelled, Detail="Cancelled")
>     at at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>     at at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>     at at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>     at at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>     at at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg)
>     at at Grpc.Core.Calls.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](CallInvocationDetails`2 call, TRequest req)
>     at at Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
>     at at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx)
>     at at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation)
>     at at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
>     at Security.SecurityService.SecurityServiceClient.Login(User request, CallOptions options) in C:\Projects\Haacht\Haacht\Haacht\Haacht.Common\obj\Debug\SecurityGrpc.cs:122
>     at Security.SecurityService.SecurityServiceClient.Login(User request, Metadata headers, Nullable`1 deadline, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Projects\Haacht\Haacht\Haacht\Haacht.Common\obj\Debug\SecurityGrpc.cs:118
>     at Haacht.Web.Controllers.LoginController.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Login>b__0(Channel channel) in C:\Projects\Haacht\Haacht\Haacht\Haacht.Web\Controllers\LoginController.cs:30
>     at Haacht.Web.Controllers.MesController.<InvokeServiceAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\Haacht\Haacht\Haacht\Haacht.Web\Controllers\MesController.cs:25

No clue what raised this error, StackTrace also doesn't give me much information. This worked fine before I re-installed on new computer.

Comment: What version of gRPC are you using.  I saw this under certain circumstances (client hosted in a WPF/Prism application) with 3.6.1 I believe.  One I updated, the problem went away.  Code may help dig deaper into why you might be seeing this

Comment: It's version 1.22. Code is hard to include since it's a lot of code. I have a website with service which acts as a client. And other project as server which depends on a Shared project where the reference Grpc is included

Comment: Can you enable more details for error? by following : services.AddGrpc(options => {
 options.EnableDetailedErrors = true; // Enabling error details
This error can be anything, from bad format to already used channel ..., so you need to print more details.